# Listbox bindind from another listbox

Tags: c#, winforms

i have two list boxes in my form and a button in between these two boxes. In the first box i binded some data from the database and from this list box i have to select the items and should display those selected items in the second list box. this should happen when i click a button.i used the following code.i used a hash table.

```
private void btnCATAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
    ht.Add(lbCATallSubcat.SelectedValue.ToString(),
                                    lbCATallSubcat.Text.ToString());
    int i = 0;
    foreach (string ent in ht.Values)
    {
       string[] name = new string[lbCATallSubcat.Items.Count];
       for (i = 0; i < lbCATallSubcat.SelectedItems.Count; i++)
       {
           name[i] = lbCATallSubcat.Text;
           this.lbCATSelectedSubcat.Items.Add(name[i]);
       }
       lbCATSelectedSubcat.DisplayMember = ht.Values.ToString();
       lbCATSelectedSubcat.ValueMember = ht.Keys.ToString();
    }
}
```

well its working fine when im selecting only single item in the first list box but im unable to display when more than one item is selectd from the first list box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `SelectedItems` property on that listbox instead `SelectedValue`. Currently your Hashtable contains only one element.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selecteditems.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Add all selected value in hashtable using loop

```
private void btnCATAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
     for(int i=0;i<lbCATallSubcat.Items.Count;i++)
      {
         if(ht.items[i].Selected)
           {
             ht.Add(lbCATallSubcat.Items[i].Value.ToString(),
                                    lbCATallSubcat.Items[i].Text.ToString());
           }
       }

      i = 0;
    foreach (string ent in ht.Values)
    {
       string[] name = new string[lbCATallSubcat.Items.Count];
       for (i = 0; i < lbCATallSubcat.SelectedItems.Count; i++)
       {
           name[i] = lbCATallSubcat.Text;
           this.lbCATSelectedSubcat.Items.Add(name[i]);
       }
       lbCATSelectedSubcat.DisplayMember = ht.Values.ToString();
       lbCATSelectedSubcat.ValueMember = ht.Keys.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the Hashtable? With `LINQ`, you can do something like:

```
public ObjHoldingData
{
     public Display { get; set; }
     public Value { get; set; }
}

public class Form
{
     Form()
     {
           var dataList = new List<ObjHoldingData>();
           //TODO: Fill list with all the data you pulled

           Listbox1.Datasource = dataList;
           Listbox1.DisplayMember = "Display";
           Listbox1.ValueMember = "Value";
     }

     protected void ButtonClick()
     {
          Listbox2.Datasource = Listbox1.SelectedItems.Cast<ObjHoldingData>().ToList();
          Listbox2.DisplayMember = "Display";
          Listbox2.ValueMember = "Value";               
     }
}
```

If you still need the `Hashtable` you can do this at the start of the button click:

```
var ht = new Hashtable(ListBox1.SelectedItems.Cast<ObjHoldingData>().ToDictionary(o => o.Display, o => o.Value));
```